# Tactile switch actuator extension methods?

Tags: switches, pcb-design, enclosure

I am not a 100% sure this is the right place to ask this, but I couldn't figure out another, more appropriate community.

I am designing a PCB for a product, which will have a tactile switch. The PCB will be placed in an enclosure, and I want the button, on the device samples I'm making, to look something like the power button in the image below:
[image]

I need a low profile/height switch at right angle, so I will be going with one of these types:
https://www.e-switch.com/product-catalog/tact/product-lines/tl3340-series-smt-sub-miniature-tactile-switch#.V-Mql5MrIck OR 
https://www.e-switch.com/product-catalog/tact/product-lines/tl1014-series-micro-miniature-right-angle-smt-tact#.V-MqtJMrIck

Also, I plan to use one of the off-the-shelf button caps available on mouser/digikey. Example:http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?mpart=1WD30&vendor=882 (image below)

[image]

The problem is that I cannot (rather do not want to) commit/finalize to a final enclosure design right now. The final enclosure could have a gap (unknown now) between the tactile switch actuator on the PCB and the side panel/edge. Hence, I need a solution to be able to, reliably, bridge the gap between the switch on the PCB and the button cap one the panel. I would loved it if I could find low height switches that come with add-on accesories for actuator extension or caps. I searched for tactile switch actuator extenders, but none of the results seem suitable for these low profile/height miniature switches.

What are some solutions/suggestions to this?? SHould I use some way other than the cap mentioned above???

I am looking for a solution that is NOT just a flimsy hack. I want something that is kinda sturdy. Also, this is for more than one device, I want to do this for the ~10-15 samples I'm making.
(Also, I understand finalizing my enclosure is the obvious one, but please understand that I do not want to do that right now.)

Also, would like to highlight that I need a 'low height' (less than 4mm tall) switch. And that where the difficulty lies. Otherwise there are tactile switches with long/variable length actuators -- but none that I could find are short (<4mm) with long actuators.

Comment: Any pointers/suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused as in what stops you in placing the 90° switch on the edge of the PCB, choosing the specific position the moment you're ready with the case design. That's the way most consumer electronics have their buttons, the other option being a small side PCB with button membranes directly on the PC as in [here](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Kq4XFrp3L._SY355_.jpg). Keep in mind that buttons with long shafts are unreliable, especially if the shaft can wobble.

Comment: I am placing it at the edge of the pcb. Just that it may be a few mm (upto like 10mm) away from the case edge. The gap tht i am talking about is just those few mm. (So separate pcb is also not wht i want to do, coz this is very small design/distance).   I was hoping there is a standard practice to handle this

Comment: I mean what's the reason you can't extend the PCB in the direction of the power button cap? It can be a small protrusion holding just the button.